# Leibniz Notation - Canceling Differentials

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I've known that Leibniz notation is misleading, because it implies that the derivative is a quotient when $h$ is infinitely small, but embarrassingly, I don't really understand why it doesn't work to consider a derivative to be a quotient.

Consider $\frac{df}{dx}$, this is the limit as $h$ goes to zero in $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$, but isn't this really the same thing as saying $$\lim _{\Delta x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta f}{\Delta x} = \frac{df}{dx}$$

I've seen this in several physics texts over the years, maybe it's just a case of being sloppy? The derivative is an infinitesimal change in a function due to an infinitesimal change in one of its variables?

How does this explain that $\frac{dx}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt}$?

Comment: $h$ does not tend to infinity, but rather $0$ and so the same goes for $\Delta x$.

Comment: Oh dear, thanks for catching that... it's my day off. I fixed it

Comment: Try to proof the chain rule using the $\lim_{h\to 0}$-definition of the derivative, you will see what is really going on, and that you need some continuity assertions in the process.

Comment: Yeah, I just got Spivak's Calculus off the bookshelf, I'll report back after having read through the relevant section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard framework of undergraduate calculus, the derivative is a limit of difference quotients, but is not itself a quotient of two quantities. There are ways to "make it work" but they are universally more confusing than calculus already is, though they have their supporters.
As for your question whether
$$\lim _{\Delta x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta f}{\Delta x} = \frac{df}{dx},$$
yes that is true by notation, but no it is not true if you mean $df$ and $dx$ are real numbers whose quotient is the derivative. You're committing the classic mistake of trying to evaluate the limit just by plugging in values. If $dx = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \Delta x$ then clearly $dx=0$. Again, there are ways to make this work but you are better off for the time being understanding and internalizing the fact that the derivative is a *limit* not a *quotient*.

As for the Liebniz notation, often at this level students are encouraged to think of $\frac{d}{dx}$ as the differentiation operator. So $\frac{df}{dx}$ is not a quotient but merely the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ applied to the function $f$.

More understanding will come with the study of differential approximations and Taylor series, where you will learn that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is the *principal linear part* of the change in $y$ as $x$ changes. This explains the old term *differential coefficient*.

Comment: I can see that now, although I'm rather curious about these methods of "making it work". 

I'm used to thinking of $\frac{d}{dx}$ as an operator.

Comment: @Astrum I recommend differential geometry.

Comment: Thanks, I see how it all works now. Differential Geometry should be an interesting topic.